# How can I automatically freeze and thaw an app on demand?

Tags: automation, titanium-backup, disable-app

I have some apps that I open on occasion. One in particular is a game that likes to push notifications up reminding me to play again.

Is there an app I can use to automatically freeze an Android app when I exit it, and automatically thaw and open the app when I want to open it again? I hate how many apps have background services or receive intents that I don't care for.

With my ROM, I can specifically deny permissions to apps based on certain intents, but that doesn't always help.

I know you can freeze and thaw an app using Titanium Backup Pro, which I have. But that would require manually going in to TiBu and doing the freeze/thaw commands each time.

In an ideal world, I would like a list of apps to be frozen as soon as I exit. And instead of the app listed in my app drawer, I would have a shortcut to first thaw the app and then open it (and have the same icon as the app). I don't care if this takes an extra few seconds; I simply want certain apps to only be running when I say so. Does this exist in any form on Android, whether in a kernel patch, an app, or a simple script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know you can freeze and thaw an app using Titanium Backup Pro, which I have. But that would require manually going in to TiBu and doing the freeze/thaw commands each time.

You're wrong about that part. Try this:

1. look for a free place on your homescreen
2. long-press there
3. select to add a widget
4. scroll to *Titanium Backup*
5. select the item to (un)freeze an app
6. select the app

This gives you a toggle-widget to freeze/unfreeze the selected app.

Comment: Didn't know about that, that's awesome.  I might actually use the Freeze feature now!

Comment: Yepp! Great for *Google Maps*: I need it maybe 3 times a year -- but it is constantly running in the background. Next time it causes trouble, I punch the widget I already prepared #-)

Comment: This is really neat. I didn't know that widget existed! However, there is still the small problem that it is a widget and not a shortcut, and thus can't be put into folders (why did they have to make it a widget anyway? It looks just like a shortcut!). But I suppose I could still live with it. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that, too. Didn't check if it's available as shortcut as well. If not, put it on your wishlist to the dev -- Joel is quite responsive normally.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger I think that widget issue still exists. You can choose to convert a widget into a normal  shortcut which can be dragged into a folder as well using an app like [Popup Widget 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.popupWidget&hl=en). See my answer for its simple usage: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/120930/96277. Of course, this issue is so old that you may have gotten an answer already.