# How to Stop apps from waking other apps?

Tags: facebook, twitter, xposed-framework, greenify

I've been running xposed on my galaxy note 2 with 4.1.1. I have greenify enabled as well as android tuner with perms blocked.  Also,  I have everything scrambled with xprivacy. I have facebbok selected for hibernation.  Everytime I open Plume, I noticed that facebook app comes out of hibernation.  I had this same problem with "Keep" months ago,  but was able to cut the directory path through greenify. I don't see that option anymore.  I have gone through and set everything I can think of to stop this,  yet facebook still wakes when I launch Plume. Also  whenever  I use  SwiftKey (which is everytime I enter text!) it also wakes Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in essence working against the Google cogs' planned L app integration/cross-communication. Integration is usually good/well received.

My first guess is that you have swiftkey set to sign in with facebook and possibly have plume (twitter) linked with facebook. Try to revoke these permissions first to see if it fixes the problem.

One thing that may help you is to get rid of the android facebook account and instead either rely on using the browsers mobile facebook page, or sign in every time. I'm not sure how much this path would muck up facebooks usability.

Another option is to set up automated facebook freezing: [How can I automatically freeze and thaw an app on demand?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34243/how-can-i-automatically-freeze-and-thaw-an-app-on-demand)

Freezing is one step beyond hibernation and no app link or background process can thaw without deliberate action.

Comment: I don't sign in to apps with facebook, never trusted facebook in that way.  But since posting this thread,  I did uninstall facebook and go with firefox mobile sign in. That works,  it's a few extra steps, but it's been fine for the past few weeks.  I never thought of freezing with titanium though! I didn't even realize titanium's widgets were that versatile. I just tried it out on plume. I may even reinstall fb and swiftkey and "keep" now. Thanks